# How to publish SQL Reporting Services (SSRS) using Web Application Proxy (WAP)?

Tags: reporting-services, reverse-proxy, adfs, adfs3.0

I'm trying to publish **SSRS 2016** Web Service & Web Portal via **Web Application Proxy** and **AD FS** on Win 2012 R2.

What configuration do I need to have on the SSRS side in order to be able to access reports via URL and WAP?

Does anyone has found a **step-by-step** guide? I've been googling for a few days without luck.

Thanks,

Comment: Any luck on a solution for publishing the SSRS web portal through the WAP?  The last paragraph of this post mentions guidance forthcoming, but I did not find that being published. [SSRS Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2017/02/02/leveraging-web-application-proxy-in-windows-server-2016-to-provide-secure-access-to-your-sql-server-reporting-services-environment/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there was any special SSRS configuration required, but here are the steps for getting the SSRS web portal published through the WAP.

One issue we had was the report path was being removed from the querystring when a report was requested.  The solution was to **encode the report path** portion of the URL.

1. Create a standard Relying Party Trust in ADFS with no claims set and the endpoint and identifier set to `https://example.com/ReportServer/`.
2. Publish an endpoint in WAP with ADFS pre-authentication and set external and internal URL to `https://example.com/ReportServer/`.
3. Use a URL like the following to access a report, `https://example.com/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx/?%2fHR-Reports%2fQ1-Report&rs:Command=Render`

**UPDATE**:

Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to be the case. There seems to be a bug with the WAP related to truncating the report path.  If you have already authenticated with ADFS and then access a report (e.g. https://example.com/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/HR-Reports/Q1-Report&rs:Command=Render), you are redirected to ADFS because the authn token is not yet set for your reports service provider (SP) as the "EdgeAccessCookie" cookie.

The reports SP (usually WAP really) redirects you to ADFS for a token with your return URL in the query string.  You've already authenticated to ADFS, so you're given a token for the SP and redirected back to your SP, but **the issue is the report path is no longer present in the query string** of your SP's URL (https://example.com/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx/?rs:Command=Render&authToken=xyz).  This causes an error at your report server.

If you then access the original URL again though (https://example.com/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/HR-Reports/Q1-Report&rs:Command=Render), you already have your authn token for the SP and your browser presents it to your SP as the EdgeAccessCookie cookie.  In this case you are not redirected to ADFS and you are able to access your report as expected.  Of course, this is less than ideal however having to access your report a 2nd time.